# Is $\{a^nb^n\}\cup\{a^nb^{2n}\}$ LR(k)?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, lr-k

I was reading Knuth's paper "On The Translation of Languages from Left to Right", my particular interest being on RL($k$) languages (not a typo). By the end of the paper, he puts the grammar:

$$
S \rightarrow Ac
\\
S \rightarrow B
\\
A \rightarrow aAbb
\\
A  \rightarrow abb
\\
B \rightarrow aBb
\\
B \rightarrow ab
$$

Which generates the language $\{a^nb^n\}\cup\{a^nb^{2n}c\}$. He states that this language is clearly RL($k$), which is easy to see, and he proves that it cannot be LR($k$). But, in his proof, he states:

> The problem is, of course, the appearance of "c" at the extreme right.

So, my doubt is: if it wasn't for the extra "c", could the language be LR($k$)? He remarks that, *of course*, the problem is the "c", but I don't see how I could write an LR($k$) grammar for $\{a^nb^n\}\cup\{a^nb^{2n}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propbably you should read the citation as: "The problem is that the c (which separates the two parts of the language) *is at the extreme right and not at the extreme left*, where we start parsing."

Therefore it is of no help (unlike the case where you start reading at the right), and therefore there is no LR-grammar for this language. Neither with the c nor without.

Comment: Right. It's RL(k) because of the $c$ (but not without).

Comment: Oh, I thought I was missing something. Thanks! :D